# var result = string.split('').forEach(...); Doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, why is result below `undefined`?

```
var x = "happy";
var result = x.split('').forEach(function(val,index,array){
   array[index] = "0";
}); 
console.log(result);
```

The output is:

```
undefined
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything. You'll want to use `map`.

Comment: @Bergi it's unclear that he actually wants a new array, he appears to be trying to modify it in-place.

Comment: did the question subject get updated to add the `var result = ` bit?

Comment: @Alnitak: Given that he just created the array using `split`, his intention seems to be getting a new array in a one-liner. Which is exactly what `map` is supposed to do. The attempt to modify anything in-place is just a side show.

Comment: Thank you all! I think my confusion came from thinking that if `split` returns something, then it doesn't matter if `forEach` returns something. The difference between `forEach` and `map` is also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `forEach` is editing the array in place.  It doesn't return an array.  Your code works with this modification:

```
var x = "happy";
var result = x.split('');
result.forEach(function(val,index,array){
   array[index] = "0";
}); 
console.log(result);
```

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
>   unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
>   not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the
>   end of a chain. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description

Answer (score 2):

`string.split('').forEach(...)` works perfectly to iterate over the characters of a string.

However `forEach` doesn't return a value, hence `result === undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated forEach does not return a value.

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var x = "happy";
var result = x.split('').map(function(val,index,array){
   return "0";
}); 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because forEach iterates over the array. It doesn't return anything.

Try this:

```
var x = "happy";
var result = [];
x.split('').forEach(function(val,index,array){
  result.push("0");
});

console.log(result);
```

With underscorejs you could write it with two lines:

```
var x = "happy";
var result = _.map(x.split(''), function(el){ return "0"; });
```